# Can someone explain the steps of execution of code?

Tags: javascript

```
function f() {
  var a = 1;

  a = 2;
  var b = g();
  a = 3;

  return b;

  function g() {
    return a;
  }
}

f(); // returns '2'
```

How is f() 2 after execution?

Comment: Why not? I mean ... what did you expect?

Comment: A is 2 at the moment it is returned and then stored in b which then gets returned. Use a debugger if this is hard to follow

Comment: `f` returns `b` which is the return of function `g` which is `a` that is set to `2` just before the b is set?

Comment: Oh, now I think I get it. When var b = g() is called, function g() is called and returns a. Earlier I was confused which return statement will be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go:

you declare `a = 1`, then you set it to `2`, now you set b to 2 because function `g()` is returning 2 because in that moment you call this function `a = 2`.

Now you set `a` to 3.

And your Function is returning `b` and b is in this case 2

Just follow the code step by step

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens line by line:

```
a is 1
a is 2
b is execution of g AT THIS POINT, which is a, which is 2
a is 3
return b, which is still 2
```

That's why you see 2 as the returned value, at the moment of assignation, b equals a which is 2.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers: In Javascript, each function has its own scope and can access the variables defined within it. But it also has access to the variables from the "outer" scope (the context from where it was declared).

In this case, `a` is a variable in the scope of `f()`, but since `g()` is being declared inside `f()`'s scope as well, it will also have access to `a`. This scenario is also known as closures in JS.
 https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

---

Answer (score 1):

after execute function `f()`  this function will see what is value this it will return 
then it will return `b` then what is the value of `b` it return function and this function return value of `a` then it will search about value of `a` and it will take last modified value of `a => 2`

```
then the rule is execute functions first 
and then search about variable values that functions contains
```